# Access HTML code in HTTP response with scapy

Tags: python, http, scapy

I have a program that uses scapy to sniff data, I'm trying to access the html returned in the http response, I can access all the headers and the response body which includes the html BUT it appears as ��Z��}ks۸���[u��ܵ�#J��/ɴ+q2��&3��s�.

Accessing packet[Raw].load returns the above result.

Now looking at the headers I can see that this is compressed with gzip, which explains why its being displayed like this, so I tried decompressing it with as GzipFile and using zlib but in both cases I got an error message stating this is not a gzip file.

Any help on decompressing it properly??

UPDATE: I noticed that the main issue is that I am trying to decompress part of the string, so the http response is being sent as chunks and the decompress method is failing because I am trying to decompress each chunk separately, if I combine all the chunks I am able to decompress using zlib and gzip, but the same question remains, can I decompress the chunks one at a time before combining them ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it with `gzip` module:

```
body_stream = StringIO.StringIO(body)
gzipper = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=body_stream)
data = gzipper.read()
print data[:25]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
I have already tried that but forgot to mention it, this is what I get
"IOError: CRC check failed 0x301d0c != 0x962589fL"